# Do my Image Widths Exceed Limit?

Tags: c#, image, file-system, console

I needed to find whether any image's width at or higher than a certain directory folder exceeds a limit.  Is this code a good way of doing this, or is there a way in which it can be improved?  I ran it over at least a couple hundred images and several hundred other files contained in the main directory (not `C:\Users`, but I don't want to show my user name), and it completed so fast the time is irrelevant.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users", "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(file);

        if (img.Width > 1100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            Console.WriteLine(img.Width);
        }

        img.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than opening a resource and then remembering to close it with a `.Dispose()` call,
I think it's good to use the `using (...) { ... }` idiom as much as possible.
Some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649308/using-image-fromfile-does-not-release-handle-on-a-file) (and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576341/open-image-from-file-then-release-lock)) on Stack Overflow suggest some issues with releasing image resources when opened with `Image.FromFile`.

I propose this alternative:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users", "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (Image img = Image.FromStream(fs))
        {
            if (img.Width > 1100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                Console.WriteLine(img.Width);
            }
        }
    }
}
```